# wpf DataGrid column index is not saved

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I developed an application to hide/unhide and reorder columns in a datagrid using WPF.

In the reordering of columns function, I change the index in the following manner.

```
foreach (var item in dataGrid.Columns)
{
     item.DisplayIndex = somenumber;
}
```

The change is reflected in the view. However if I try to read the index again, the original index is displayed i.e    `myDataGrid.Columns[0].Header` displays the original value and not the changed value. How do I reorder the datagrid indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayIndex is different from ColumnIndex.
so when you change the DisplayIndex you are changing only the order of the column not the base index in its columns array.

actually you can't replace DataGridColumn Index, but if you insist you should clear DataGridColumns and re add them programmatically as you want.
the big reason is that the DataGridColumn "Must" has belonged DataGrid parent.